# Query for comparing payments to remaining balance

Tags: oracle

There is an application for processing customer payments and calculating remaining balances. Say, a customer has a balance of $910.09. The agent logs on to the application applies $15.45 to customer. Now, the remaining balance is $894.64.

Later, the agent applies another payment of $33.65. The balance is now 894.64 - 33.65 = 860.99.

Well, there is an inherited process (say, Process X) that every single time a payment is applied, it populates my table with all the payments applied on every processing since the beginning.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_PAYMENTS
(
  CUSTOMER_NO   NUMBER,
  PAYMENT_DATE  DATE,
  PAYMENT_AMT   NUMBER(20,4),
  REM_BALANCE   NUMBER(20,4)
)
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into CUSTOMER_PAYMENTS
   (CUSTOMER_NO, PAYMENT_DATE, PAYMENT_AMT, REM_BALANCE)
 Values
   (4926, TO_DATE('05/30/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), -15.45, 894.64);
Insert into CUSTOMER_PAYMENTS
   (CUSTOMER_NO, PAYMENT_DATE, PAYMENT_AMT, REM_BALANCE)
 Values
   (4926, TO_DATE('05/30/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), -15.45, 860.99);
Insert into CUSTOMER_PAYMENTS
   (CUSTOMER_NO, PAYMENT_DATE, PAYMENT_AMT, REM_BALANCE)
 Values
  (4926, TO_DATE('05/30/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), -33.65, 860.99);
COMMIT;
```

This is what my table becomes after Process X runs twice. Now, my challenge is to identifying unique payments. How do I compare remaining balances after a payment is applied to see if it is really that number and if not i would say this is duplicate?

In this case, the 3rd row 894.64 - 15.45 != 860.99. Therefore, 2nd row 15.45 is duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your Customer_Payments table have a primary key, or anything to indicate what order the payments were inserted in?

Comment: Nope. Again, this is inherited from a 3rd party.

Comment: you said "the 3rd row ...therefore, 2nd row is duplicate".  Once in the db, there is no 3rd row or 2nd row, unless you're ordering the results.  To @Gerrat question, you need a sane way to differentiate between payments.  I won't say what I think about Process X :-)

Comment: Without the correct order of records coming in, this becomes pretty impossible.. Can you add a trigger on the tables to somehow stamp an ID to enable you to know the correct order?  Or is there another table this can join to that has the correct order?

Comment: @tbone, i used row numbers for the sake of this example. In Q/A environment, first time I run the process, it created 44 records. Apply a payment, then run the process again then I have 44+45=89 records.

Comment: @Craig, what if they actually post two same amounts back to back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't think this can be answered reliably, since there is no way to be certain of the ordering.  If one were to assume that the remaining balance should be decreasing, this might give you some dups to look at:

```
SELECT customer_no, payment_date, payment_amt, rem_balance, prev_bal
FROM (
    SELECT customer_no, payment_date, payment_amt, rem_balance,     
    LAG(rem_balance, 1,  0) OVER   
    (PARTITION BY customer_no ORDER BY rem_balance DESC) prev_bal,
    rownum r
    FROM customer_payments
    ORDER BY rem_balance DESC
)
WHERE r > 1 and
prev_bal + payment_amt <> rem_balance
ORDER BY customer_no, rem_balance DESC
```

[[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c52a/18) here.]

[I'm making lots of assumptions here though - like rem_balance is always decreasing, and never 999999999999 normally,  etc.]

Comment: yes! the remaining balance has to be decreasing. I think you are on to something, but i get an error : Error at line 9
ORA-00904: "NEXT_BAL": invalid identifier

Comment: Ok, I added another level - better now?

Comment: WHERE     rem_balance >= next_bal
      --   AND payment_amt > 0    BOOM!

Comment: I think it was a little off, so I tweaked, and added a SQL Fiddle.